# Spring LDAP multiple queries in single call

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap

We are using spring LDAP to search record based on given CN as below.

```
AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
filter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectClass", "ldapsubentry"));
filter.and(new EqualsFilter("cn", "ABCD"));
List<ModelandRulsetVO> result = ldapTemplate.search(userSearchBase, filter.encode(), 2,new ModelAndRuleSetMapper());
```

where ABCD is CN name. Now for multiple CNs we need to call above code multiple times for each CN. 
Is there any way in spring ldap to do this in single call or can we can pass multiple values with comma seperated like

```
filter.and(new EqualsFilter("cn", "ABCD,XYZ,DEF")) ?
```

Comment: There is no way in LDAP, let alone Spring LDAP.